# Assigning value to element of a cstring

Tags: c, c-strings

Just learned about cstrings in my computer science class and it just hit me,
this is legal

```
char ch[] = "hello";
```

However, it seems that I can also assign to the "5th" element in this array

```
ch[5] = "!";
```

Is this allowed? Or am I just overriding the null character at the end of the array?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not allowed. As you said, this is overwriting the null-character at the end. It doesn't cause an error at this point, because you are accessing a valid index.

But if you try to print the string, then the print function doesn't know where the string ends. The print function will keep printing the characters until it reaches a zero byte by accident, or something else goes horribly wrong with buffer overflow. This is undefined behavior. The same problem will occur with other string functions, `strcpy`, `strlen`, `strcmp`... who all rely on the null-character to find the end of string.